# Calling a custom hook with a parameter from a custom component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have this custom hook I want to be executed when pressing a button inside a custom component

```
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { useCallback } from 'react';
import { retireUserFromEvents } from '../../../redux/actions/Events';

export default function useDeleteAssistantToEvent() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const deleteAssistantToEvent = useCallback(userID => {
    dispatch(retireUserFromEvents(userID));
  }, [dispatch]);

  return deleteAssistantToEvent;
}
```

I declare the hook on the screen where the custom component is:

```
import {
  AttendantList
} from '../../../../components';
import useDeleteAssistantToEvent from '../../../../hooks/assistance/useDeleteAssistantToEvent';

export default function EventAssistantsView({ navigation }) {
  const deleteAssistant = useDeleteAssistantToEvent();

  return (
    <SafeAreaProvider>
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.safeAreaViewStyle}>
        <View style={styles.mainViewStyle}>
          <AttendantList
            ...
            undoInvite={() => deleteAssistant}
          />
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </SafeAreaProvider>
  );
}
```

And this is my custom component (AttendantList):

```
export default function AttendantList({ attendees, goToUserProfile, undoInvite, imHostOrCohost }) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.mainViewStyle}>
      {attendees.length > 0 ? (
        <FlatList
          ...
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={goToUserProfile()}>
              <InviteCard
                ...
                onPress={() => undoInvite(item.id)}
              />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          )}
        />
      ) : (
        ...
      )}
    </View>
  );
}
```

`ÌnviteCard` is the button in question.

The problem is that, anytime I want to press the button, nothing happens. So, how can I pass the hook call to the custom component?

Comment: You're not calling the delete function. It should be `undoInvite={() => deleteAssistant()}`, or even simpler, just `undoInvite={deleteAssistant}`, since `deleteAssistant` is already a function

Comment: @Jayce444 but what about the parameter ```deleteAssistant``` takes?

Comment: You're not passing in a parameter at that intermediate point, you do that inside the attendant list component with `onPress={() => undoInvite(item.id)}`. That part is fine.